# WebApiConfig does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc 5.I'm doing the following tutorial,
http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/

but in the Global.sax file it says that "WebApiConfig does not exist in current context".why is that?

here are some codes

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); //this is where error shows
        //Start SqlDependency with application initialization
        SqlDependency.Start(connString);
    }
```

Comment: have you made sure any assemblies needed for WebApi is not missing? or any version mismatch?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you have a WebApiConfig.cs file in your App_Start folder?
If you take a look at the source that the tutorial references in github then the WebApiConfig file is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace SignalRDbUpdates
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the App_Start folder on the github repository:
https://github.com/venkatbaggu/signalrdatabasenotifications/tree/master/SignalRDbUpdates/App_Start

Comment: Thanks..WebApiConfig file was missing

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had moved the code folder, and for some reason the

```
WebApiConfig.cs
AuthConfig.cs
Filter.cs
BundleConfig.cs
```

had been excluded from the project, reincluded them and it worked again.
Because the folder wasn't expanded I never realised that they had been excluded.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear when you get this error, at compile time or when debugging?

If it happens during compilation then check if `WebApiConfig.cs` file exists.

If it's happening when you debugging, then you need to check if you made some changes in this file, because default implementation should work without a problem.

Maybe the problem is with next line?

```
SqlDependency.Start(connString);
```

Check if connections string is correct.

**EDIT:**
I tried to download and run the project and first I got this error:

> Entering break mode failed for the following reason: Source file
>   'e:\BlogDemos\SignalRDbUpdates\SignalRDbUpdates\Global.asax.cs' does
>   not belong to the project being debugged

Which is strange, because I don't have "E" drive at all. But after changing `Managaed Pipilene Mode` to `Classic` and back to `Integrated` (default value) and building the project it started to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you.WebApiConfig file was missing.. but when i run the app now there is an unhandled  exception at SqlDependency.Start(connString);

Comment: You need to check that your connection string "DefaultConnection" is correct. If `SqlDependency` continues to throw exceptions, then you might first try to test connection by using something simple like [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(v=vs.110).aspx). And the continue with `SqlDependency` class.